# Multivariable Calculus?

Tags: inequality

Hello Everyone im stuck with this problem
Given a,b,c,d four real numbers within [0,1] and $K = |a-b||a-c||a-d||b-c||b-d||c-d|$ such that K is maximum
Show that $K<\frac{1}{27}$

I really don't know from where to start
My idea is studying a 4 variable function but I don't see how I can do it

Any hint will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: I disagree with the statement of the problem. If we're choosing $a,b,c,d$ to make $K$ a maximum, then $K=1/27$ (choose $a=0$, $b=1/3$, $c=2/3$, and $d=1$).

Comment: @TedShifrin: Check your numerics.

Comment: I don't see how K=1/27 for those values I have 4/3^5 instead

Comment: Oh, yeah, of course, @Christian, I didn't multiply all six distances. My apologies. But I guess that's the clue to the solution :)  Let's choose $0\le a<b<c<d\le 1$ and maximize $(b-a)(c-b)(d-c)$. Then the quantity in question is clearly less than that.

Comment: @arsenestein: Yes, you're right. I screwed up. I got $(b-a)(c-b)(d-c) = 1/27$, and then I needed to multiply by $(c-a)(d-a)(d-b) = 2/3\cdot 1\cdot 2/3 = 4/9$.

Comment: If you want, you can first check that $K$ is well-defined as a maximum.

Observe that $K<\max |a-b||b-c||c-d|$.

In order to maximize the RHS, we can assume without loss of generality that $0\le a<b<c<d\le 1$. Then we want to maximize $(b-a)(c-b)(d-c)$.

Observe that we have to choose $d=1,a=0$. So we want to maximize $b(c-b)(1-c)$. Using AM-GM inequality for three variables, we find that this gets maximized by $b=\frac13, c=\frac23$ with a value of $\frac1{27}$.

Answer (score 2):

We may assume $0\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq d\leq 1$. It is clear that the product of the six distances is maximal when $a=0$ and $d=1$. Therefore it is sufficient to compute the maximum of
$$f(b,c):=b\,c\,1\,(c-b)\,(1-b)\,(1-c)\qquad(0\leq b\leq c\leq 1)\ .$$
When $b$ or $c$ are $=0$ or $=1$, or when $b=c$, we have $f(b,c)=0$. It follows that $f$ takes its maximum at an interior point of $[0,1]^2$. Solving the system
$$f_b(b,c)=0,\quad f_c(b,c)=0$$
gives the unique point
$$b={5-\sqrt{5}\over10},\quad c={5+\sqrt{5}\over10}$$
satisfying $0<b< c<1$. Computing
$$f(b,c)={1\over25\sqrt{5}}<{1\over27}$$
gives the maximal value of the $K$ in the problem.

Comment: Wow! I really appreciate this method thanks